# jQuery Mobile JSON issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've been trying to pick up jQuery Mobile in my free time and I'm trying to stitch together an app with the League of Legends, Riot API. I have a basic framework put together in notepad where on the first page, a summoner name would be entered and on clicking the search button or on the creation of the second page, it would access the api and display the basic summoner information from the name.

I can't seem to get my script call right though and I don't know where else to look to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there's any other information that I missed out on, don't hesitate to ask. (good test Summoner name is blksheep93)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>League Of Legends Coach Web Application</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                <p>This is an ongoing test page for my League of Legends Statistical Analysis and Coaching application</p>
                <p>Please enter your summoner name in the text box below.</p>
                 <h2>Enter Your Summoner Name</h2>

                <div class="ui-field-contain">
                    <input type="text" name="SumName" id="SumName" placeholder="Summoner Name">
                    <br>    <a href="#pagetwo" id="callSum" class="ui-btn">Search</a>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                 <h1>Footer Text</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
                    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div id="resultLog"></div>
                <label id="testLabel" for="test">Test Label</label>
                <ul data-role="listview" id="Summoner" data-theme="a"></ul> <a href="#pageone">Go to Page One</a>

            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
                 <h1>Footer Text</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            (function($) {
                $(document).on('pageinit', '#pagetwo', function()) {
                    var url = 'https://na.api.pvp.net';
                    var spec = '/api/lol/{region}/v1.4/summoner/by-name/';
                    var user = $("#SumName").val();
                    var key = '?api_key=7839f0aa-82ac-47b9-8c4b-0eae4e2e39cc';
                    var url2 = url + spec + user + key;
                    $(#testLabel).val() = $('url2');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url + spec + user+key,
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        async: true,
                        success: function(result) {
                            ajax.parseJSONP(result);
                        },
                        error: function(request, error) {
                            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                        }
                    });

                    $.getJSON(url2, function(data)) {

                        $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
                            $('#Summoner').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + item.id + '"><h3>' + item.name + '</h3><p>" Summoner Level: "' + item.summonerLevel '</p></a></li>');
                            $('#Summoner').listview('refresh');
                        }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Edit:
I fixed the little issue with the movieName. Not sure how it got there but it's the way it should be now. After I run it the console tells me 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) /C:/Users/Tiko/Documents/jQuery/Program%20Files/SummonerSearch.html:53 
which I believe (again, notepad) is the start of the script file. Nothing on the url2 from the console log.

Comment: After the -- var url2 -- add -- console.log(url2); -- and check the console output of the browser to see what url is showing. Copy the url and paste it in a new browser window and hit enter. Do you see any json callback data appear???? i get "Access denied" so it may be your API key is invalid. Can you double check

Comment: `movieName` is not defined. The `{region}` path variable is never populated, as far as I can see.

Comment: $(#testLabel).val() = $('url2');

# is an invalid character to have in a variable. Furthermore, you probably are trying to do something like this instead: $('#testLabel').val(url2); instead of... well whatever you think it was doing there.

Also your ajax success function has ajax.parseJSONP(result), where 1: it doesn't look like ajax has been defined anywhere and 2: ajax.parseJSONP doesnt look like it actually exists -- did you want $.parseJSON?

Comment: Also you have an extra ) at the end of your functions: $(document).on('pageinit', '#pagetwo', function()) -- drop that last ) as well as the one at the end of $.getJSON(url2, function(data)) Then you'll need to close the functions at the appropriate spots with })

Comment: I'm trying to get the JSON object from the Riot servers via the API. This is technically my first time playing around with jQuery Mobile (and javascript actually) so I apologize if I missed a lot of the more simple parts of the program.

Comment: the $(#testLabel.val()= part was my trying to test to see if it got that far in the code by simply outputting the value of variable url2 to the testLabel

Comment: @user3689303 if you want to stay away from a full-blown IDE, i would recommend using something like notepad++ which will at least give you syntax highlighting, matching bracket/parenthesis highlighting, etc... http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code. There was a lot wrong with it, mostly syntax errors. I have added comments in the JavaScript to try to help you see what was wrong. Please read up on JavaScript if you want to get better than just copy/paste coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>League Of Legends Coach Web Application</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>This is an ongoing test page for my League of Legends Statistical Analysis and Coaching application</p>
        <p>Please enter your summoner name in the text box below.</p>
        <h2>Enter Your Summoner Name</h2>

        <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <input type="text" name="SumName" id="SumName" placeholder="Summoner Name">
            <br>    <a href="#pagetwo" id="callSum" class="ui-btn">Search</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>

    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="pagetwo">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="resultLog"></div>
        <label id="testLabel" for="test">Test Label</label>
        <ul data-role="listview" id="Summoner" data-theme="a"></ul> <a href="#pageone">Go to Page One</a>

    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Footer Text</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            (function($) {
                $(document).on('pagecreate', '#pagetwo', function() { // removed extra ) after function()
                    var url = 'https://na.api.pvp.net';
                    // replaced {region} with na
                    var spec = '/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/';
                    var user = $("#SumName").val();
                    var key = '?api_key=7839f0aa-82ac-47b9-8c4b-0eae4e2e39cc';
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url + spec + user+ key,
                        dataType: "json", // riot api does not support jsonp, fortunately it does support cross-domain-request
                        success: function(result) { // removed extra ) after function()
                            // moved the appending of the item to inside this success callback
                            console.log(result)
                            $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                                console.log(item);
                                $('#Summoner').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + item.id + '"><h3>' + item.name + '</h3><p>" Summoner Level: "' + item.summonerLevel + '</p></a></li>');
                                $('#Summoner').listview('refresh');
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(request, error) {
                            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                        }
                    }); // closed your function
                }); // closed your function
            })(jQuery); // closed your function, passed in jQuery
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```